# Airflow basic authentification causes "Too many redirects" on login page

Tags: airflow

I set in my **airflow.cfg**:

```
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

And I think, that i`d able to see login page then I open http://localhost:8089/admin, but I can only see "Too many redirects" page, logs looks like a:

```
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
airflow_webserver_1           | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2019:06:35:53 +0000] "GET /admin/airflow/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Have no ideas why it doesn`t work...

Comment: Hi, Did you added user ?

Comment: Hello, no, I thought auth screen should appear despite having created user, isn`t it?
I wanted to create user after making sure everything works

Comment: This log looks like login fails. try adding user and try it

Comment: This occurs when user doesn't have role associated with it. Edit roles associated to user adding at least one rule.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is running into this issue, try this remedy (GNU/Linux Mint 20):
There are two python's version on my system: `3.8` and `3.9`. By default I was using `3.9` and got `too many redirects` error, then found this note:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/supported-versions.html
it is said that airflow 2.5.2 is used with python 3.8 so I installed
venv with Python 3.8: `python3.8 -m venv myenv`.

go to `myenv`, run `source bin/activate`.

Then further install packages via `pip3.8` command:

```
pip3.8 install notebook

pip3.8 install pandas

pip3.8 install scikit-learn

pip3.8 install psycopg2 (I am using Postgresql)
```

make directory for airflow:
`mkdir ~/airflow`

set env var:
`export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`

then run:
`pip3.8 install apache-airflow`

`pip3.8 install apache-airflow-providers-amazon`

`pip install mlflow`

After that I started `airflow standalone` to generate `airflow.cfg` in the home dir folder.

Then made some tweaks:

`sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow_user:airflow_pass@localhost/airflow_db`
(the postgres user should've been created before with the password assigned).
`executor = LocalExecutor`

I didn't want to use email service. So I commented out these fields:

`smtp_host`, `smtp_user`, `smtp_password`, `smtp_port`, `smtp_mail_from`.

After that create user:

```
airflow users create \
 --username username \
 --firstname YOURNAME \
 --lastname LASTNAME \
 --role Admin \
 --password <password> \
 --email <email>
```

then I run the airflow again and `too many redirect` error gone away.

Hope this will help someone else to troubelshoot this issue.